# How do I keep a synced copy of a file from a github submodule

Tags: github, git-submodules

If I make a new github repo and add this as a recursive updated submodule https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/tree/42683d2cbec309750a30ce5d055b12937b9fd2f7, how do I bring a copy of the data.json file into my repo that stays fully synchronized with any changes made in the repo?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, would would use a symlink (symbolic link: `ln -s caniuse/data.json`) in your parent repository.

That way, any change made in the submodule repo file would be visible in your project.